# Passing values to a Constructor which takes pointers parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I am very new to C++ and I am trying to initialize an object called `GameObject`, in a class called `Room`, which holds a `gameObjects array`. The constructor of the `GameObject` class takes `pointers` as the parameters to initialize the fields. But I keep getting the error saying that there is "No matching constructor for initialization of `GameObject`. Could someone tell me what is my mistake here?

Sorry if this question is formatted badly, I am not used to asking C++ questions with multiple header files and source files. But please also correct me on this.

***GameObject***

```
GameObject::GameObject(string* _name, string* _description, char* _keyWord):
name(_name), description(_description), keyWord(_keyWord){
}
```

***Room***

```
//error!, "No matching constructor for initialization..."
    gameObjects[0] = new GameObject("knife", "a knife", 'k'); 
    gameObjects[1] = new GameObject("sword", "a sword", 's'); 

};
```

Comment: Why `std::string*`s instead of `std::string`s?

Comment: (a) Please read [ask] with a [mcve] as the class declarations would be useful in answering the question.  (b) `string*` parameters are unusual, I would expect either `string const &`  or just `string` (for a sink parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you in the GameObject constuctor:

```
GameObject::GameObject(string* _name, string* _description, char* _keyWord):
name(_name), description(_description), keyWord(_keyWord){}
```

You are accepting the two strings and a char by pointer. So maybe you meant to accept them by reference instead like this:

```
GameObject::GameObject(string& _name, string& _description, char _keyWord):
name(_name), description(_description), keyWord(_keyWord){}
```

Which works fine.

For instance take this program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

struct my_obj
{
    my_obj(std::string s, std::string s_, char c)
    : s__(s), s___(s_), char_(c) {}

    std::string s__{};
    std::string s___{};
    char char_{};
};

struct my_obj_2
{
    my_obj(std::string* s, std::string* s_, char* c)
    : s__(s), s___(s_), char_(c) {}

    std::string s__{};
    std::string s___{};
    char char_{};
};

int main()
{
    my_obj my_obj_1("Hello", "Goodbye", 'C'); // works fine

    my_obj_2 m_my_obj_2("Hello", "Goodbye", 'c'); // doesn't work fine
}
```

(1): This works fine because it finds a matching constructor:

> std::string -> std::string

(2): Whereas this doesnt work fine because it is this conversion:

> std::string -> std::string*

So in conclusion just remove the pointers on the constructor and if you wanted to you could pass then by `&` or `const &` like this

```
GameObject::GameObject(string& _name, string& _description, char _keyWord):
name(_name), description(_description), keyWord(_keyWord){}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry stupid error by me. i think it is because somehow when i was making the anwer part got deleted then everything was in the wrong place. But eddited it now:)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand it now. Sorry if the question was abit confusing, I had trouble finding the right words to describe my problem and am just so lost in C++...